# Angular JS - Focus on dyamically created text box

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a table in which one item is editable. On clicking that item, the text changes to a text box and it can be edited. The issue is, on clicking the text, the text changes to textbox but I'm not able to focus on the textbox. 
This is the code

JS

```
$scope.togglePrice = function (item) {
    item.showUpdatePrice = true;
}
```

HTML

```
<a ng-click="togglePrice(item)" ng-hide="item.showUpdatePrice" style="text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;">{{item.sellingPrice | currencyFormat}}</a>

<input id="updatePriceId" ng-model="item.sellingPrice" class="form-control" ng-class="{'errorClass': showPriceError}" ng-show="item.showUpdatePrice" ng-blur="saveUpdatedPrice(item)" type="text" placeholder="Enter Price">
```

**Edit**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in shoppingItems">
<tr>
<td class="priceDiv">
<div>
<a ng-click="togglePrice(item)" ng-hide="item.showUpdatePrice" style="text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;">{{item.sellingPrice | currencyFormat}}</a>
<input ng-model="item.sellingPrice" auto-focus class="form-control" ng-class="{'errorClass': showPriceError}" ng-show="item.showUpdatePrice" ng-blur="saveUpdatedPrice(item)" type="text" placeholder="Enter Price">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a small change to your method and should add one **directive** to achieve your solution.

```
$scope.togglePrice = function (item) {
    item.showUpdatePrice = !item.showUpdatePrice;

}
```

**In this solution, on click on the `text-boxes`, the respective textbox gets focussed, and on blur or clicking outside,  it gets unfocussed.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

Click to focus on Below TextBoxes: 
<table ng-controller="myCtrl">

<tbody ng-repeat="item in shoppingItems">
<tr>
<td class="priceDiv">
<div>
<a ng-click="togglePrice(item)" ng-hide="item.showUpdatePrice"  style="text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;">{{item.sellingPrice}}</a>
<input ng-model="item.sellingPrice" auto-focus class="form-control" ng-class="{'errorClass': showPriceError}" ng-show="item.showUpdatePrice" ng-blur="saveUpdatedPrice(item)" type="text" placeholder="Enter Price" focus-me="item.showUpdatePrice">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
 $scope.togglePrice = function (item) {
     item.showUpdatePrice = !item.showUpdatePrice;
        
 }

  $scope.shoppingItems = [
    {
      "showUpdatePrice" : false,
      "sellingPrice" : "10"
    },
    {
      "showUpdatePrice" : false,
      "sellingPrice" : "20"
    },
 {
      "showUpdatePrice" : false,
      "sellingPrice" : "30"
    },
  ]
});
app.directive('focusMe', ['$timeout', '$parse', function ($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.focusMe);
            scope.$watch(model, function (value) {
                if (value === true) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        element[0].focus();
                    });
                }
            });
            element.bind('blur', function () {
                scope.$apply(model.assign(scope, false));
            });
        }
    };
}]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**PLEASE RUN THE ABOVE SNIPPET**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/U0rV1W5zvsLclJNubgri?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with below code, may be it helps you. It will add a unique id to your `inputs` according to index. So you can simply access them using most efficient `javascript` `selector`.

Change your `javascript` to

```
  $scope.togglePrice = function (item, buttonClicked) {
    item.showUpdatePrice = true;
    setTimeout(function(){ 
       document.getElementById(buttonClicked).focus();
    });
  }
```

And in `html`

```
  <tbody ng-repeat="item in shoppingItems">
   <tr>
    <td class="priceDiv">
     <div>
       <a ng-click="togglePrice(item, $index)" ng-hide="item.showUpdatePrice" style="text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;">{{item.sellingPrice | currencyFormat}}</a>
       <input id='{{$index}}' ng-model="item.sellingPrice" auto-focus class="form-control" ng-class="{'errorClass': showPriceError}" ng-show="item.showUpdatePrice" ng-blur="saveUpdatedPrice(item)" type="text" placeholder="Enter Price">
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Try this May be it helps you. Thanks

Comment: I tried this. Not working, On the page load itself, the directive is getting triggered, at that time no textbox is displayed. only on click of the text the textbox is visible.

Comment: This is a table, for each row there will be a textbox with the id updatePriceId. So Id wont work

Comment: @I'mnidhin Ok got it, updating my answer.

Comment: @I'mnidhin are you using ng-repet to display this data ? if yes then please share your ng-repeat code.

Comment: ng-repeat added

Comment: @I'mnidhin updated my answer, please check and let me know if there is any issue. thanks